# Build interconnected armature

Tags: armature, bones, bone.constraints

I'm fairly new to blender and am trying to build a collection of bones that move depending on the rotation of one bone.

I have three bones (as seen in the screenshot). There are two fixed points (A and B). There should only one roational axis (Z). My goal is to only rotate B around the Z-axis and have all the other bones follow, while point A stays fixed.
In the screenshot the left picture shows the original position and the right picture the position after a rotation around B. Note: The bones A and B are not necessarily parallel.

How do I need to connect the bones? And what constraints to I need to set?

I'm using Blender 3.5.

Regards

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3DBear's answer works fine, but I'll suggest an alternative way, using only one constraint: the Inverse Kinematics constraint:

[image]

In this set up, all the bones follow the same direction in the chain. Also, there's an extra bone at the tip of the 3rd bone, that is the IK target. After creating that last bone, select it and press ALT+P to unparent it, so it's a loose bone. But don't move it, keep it's location at the tip of the 3rd bone. Rename that extra bone so it's easy to find (I renamed it "IK Target", but you can rename it however you want).

Then select the 3rd bone and add a bone constraint called "Inverse Kinematics". In the target slot select the armature and in the bone slot select the target bone (in my case, the one I named "IK Target". Increase the "chain length" to 2 (so 2 bones down the chain are affected by the constraint). If your bones are all aligned in the same 2D plane you don't need to worry about adding a 'Pole Target'. Also uncheck the "Strech" checkbox so the bone doesn't stretch if the target gets further than the length of the bones.

Now, with this constraint the 3rd bone will always follow the target (in pose mode). If you keep the target still you can rotate the first bone and the tip of the 3rd bone will stay anchored to the same point (where the target is):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd suggest keeping the main bone as the parent. If you gonna rotate B bone then let it be the parent of C. If I understood you right, you gonna need only two constaints: Copy Rotation (with the Local sapce for both Target and Owner) on the A bone, and Stretch To (with Head/Tail parameter = 1) on your C bone:

[**The result**](https://i.gyazo.com/a0b18f7b0a77b416fdfcb022f359c9a6.mp4)

P.S. You may need to press cross near the Original Length (Reset original length) in the Stretch To constraint if the C bone looks messed up after the setup.

[image]